# Supply host fingerprint for openssh at execution time rather than in known_hosts

Tags: ssh, security

I have an ephemeral CI runner that needs to execute a command on a server I own/administrate. This runner is built and torn down each CI run, so I am trying to limit the statefulness of the runner, including the creation of files such as `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. In the execution script on the CI runner I am supplying the secret key with `ssh-add - <<< "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}"` which adds the key to a running process rather than a file.

I know that openssh has options such as `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` which can avoid the fingerprint/pub-key checking, but this is an obvious security issue that I would like to avoid.

I am looking for an option in the openssh tool suite to supply a fingerprint/pub-key for that server as an argument to `ssh` while avoiding creating a `known_hosts` file. I am aware of `ssh-keyscan remotehost`, but that either needs to be directed into `known_hosts` (ideally avoided) or compared with the known pub-key in an if/then block before running the actual `ssh` command with an insecure `StrictHostKeyChecking` option (still open to MITM attack on second communication to server).

Does anything like `ssh -o ExpectFingerprint=SHA256:KNOWNFINGERPRINT user@remotehost mycommand.sh` exist to specify the "known host fingerprint" as part of the execution arguments? Given my security goals, do I have to use the `known_hosts` file on the short-lived CI runner?

Answer (score 2):

One alternative to having the host fingerprint stored in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` is to have an SSHFP RR-record in the DNS.
You need to run ssh-keygen on the server to create a set of record-entries that then needs to be added to the zone on your *DNSSEC*-enabled DNS-server:
`ssh-keygen -r host.example.com`

To check that zone is answering fingerprint queries:
`dig -t SSHFP host.example.com`

On the client you can then do this to connect to the server:
`ssh -o "VerifyHostKeyDNS=yes" host.example.com`

See also [SSHFP: Authenticate SSH Fingerprints via DNSSEC](https://weberblog.net/sshfp-authenticate-ssh-fingerprints-via-dnssec/)